# How to create a toolbar with "Search" Finder style, rounded buttons working like radio

Tags: cocoa

I want to implement a toolbar having same 'search' Finder style, using standard NSSegmentControl doesn't work.

How can I create that? The figure below shows what I want

[image: Toolbar with button acting like radio]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [MGScopeBar](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/28/mgscopebar).