# How to create a scope bar?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

In my application I need a scope bar like the one in the Dictionary.
In the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW3) it is described that something like "scope bar" exists however I couldn't find any information how to create it.
Does anyone know how to create it in the Xcode 4?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create a toolbar with “Search” Finder style, rounded buttons working like radio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117488/how-to-create-a-toolbar-with-search-finder-style-rounded-buttons-working-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code for a control like this I'm aware of is [MGScopeBar](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/28/mgscopebar/).