# Make an NSToolbar's fullScreenAccessoryView visible at launch

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fullscreen, nstoolbar

I am trying to make an application with a toolbar controller which view is shown, and for each view shown I want to include a second 'row' for the toolbar, and I found out that to do this you had to do `[toolbar setFullScreenAccessoryView:view]`.  However, the view does not appear until the user toggles fullscreen mode and the accessory view remains after toggling the window back to windowed mode.  I would like it to look like the following examples from Mail.app, Preview.app, Dictionary.app:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a toolbar with "Search" Finder style, rounded buttons working like radio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117488/how-to-create-a-toolbar-with-search-finder-style-rounded-buttons-working-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just place a custom view underneath the NSToolbarView .. so at the top of the window.
dont misuse the fullscreenAccessory view. it if meant for something else.

see [How to create a toolbar with "Search" Finder style, rounded buttons working like radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117488/how-to-create-a-toolbar-with-search-finder-style-rounded-buttons-working-like)

(it could be any other view too btw :D)

Comment: So I know for the future, what is the proper way to use fullScreenAccessory view?

Comment: when you have a view.. in a ... e.g. floating palette.. and in fullscreen you don't want the palette but you need one view in it you mark THAT as a fullScreenAccessory. The toolbar will then take that view as 2nd row when the palette is hidden

Comment: just an example... it could also be that you have a sidebar that in fullscreen turns into a bar

Comment: or a view that is hidden in a menu but in fullscreen it makes sense to always show it

Comment: The answer to that question provides source code that is not compatible with ARC

Comment: @PythonSpoilsYou yes? and? :) the point is that it is ANY custom view. Arc or not doesn't matter at all. but maybe someone finds an arcified view ;)